# problem getting current url when cache is turned on

Tags: magento2, cache

**Summary**

- This problem is affecting my Venus Theme Mega Menu module.
- When caching is turned on the menu no longer shows correct .active classes for the current page.
- I'm looking in the module code where the .active page is set (`app/code/Ves/Megamenu/Helper/Data.php`)
- The default magento menu does not suffer this problem.
- I'm using SSL for storefront pages

**Details**

When caching is turned *off* the following two vendor methods both return the correct current url:

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl()
```

and

```
$this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl()
```

When caching is turned *on* both methods return only the URL of the first page that is loaded after the cache is turned on.

Example

- **cache:enable** then **cache:flush**
- first page loaded is https://myurl/first-page
- both methods return this as the current url
- go to page https://myurl/next-page
- both methods still return https://myurl/first-page as the current URL
- and the same URL is returned by both methods for all subsequent pages I visit

Does anyone know why the caching should interfere with these methods and if there is anything I can do to correct it.